# How can I take photos off my iPhone automatically?

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app, photo-stream, dropbox

I shoot a lot of photos and videos so my iPhone fills up often.

The way I deal with it now is a time-wasting chore. I connect my phone to my computer. Dropbox automatically sucks my photos & videos to my computer. Then I use a mass-delete app to remove the photos from my phone.

I know I can use Dropbox on my phone, but it takes too long for the photos to upload.

What I'd like is something that automatically moves older photos to the cloud. Then I'd like to access those photos from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**iCloud Photo Library** with "Optimize device storage enabled" will make a copy of your full resolution photos and videos, and will leave a small copy on your device, if storage space is needed. It will not remove them but it will sync changes made in all connected devices (deletes, edits, albums).